# Database and SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I know I've asked a similar question before but I still can't get this working.

I'm using C# in VS2010

What I'm doing is creating an application that takes user entered words in `textbox1` clicks a button and all words with `"*"` in front of them print in `textbox2`

I'm using a SQL Server database to do this because I want the `"*"` words to be stored in the database so I can later add a counter to show how many times that word has been entered.

For example:

- User enters `the cat is *brown` in `textbox1`, presses a button, then `*brown` appears in `textbox2`

My code for SQL Server is this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=StoreList;Integrated Security=sspi");

con.Open();
String queryStr = "SELECT item FROM StoreList WHERE item LIKE '*%'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(queryStr, con);
SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();

while (sdr.Read())
{
   this.textbox2.Text = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
}

sdr.Close();
```

What I need help with is how to further that code to get the app working. So I don't know how to make it get the word from textbox1.

Any help guys?

Comment: Any other answers would be appreciated greatly as nothing i've tried works

Comment: Please have a look at my answer I have edited it so that you can also do it without the stored procedure, using 2 separate lines of SQL

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring your code example it seems to me there are a couple of things going on here.

1. You want to built a list of star'd words entered into textbox1
2. You want to output the star'd word list to textbox2
3. Store a frequency list of the stared words

Points 1 and 2 can be done without interaction with the database. Perhaps using a regex to pattern match words being with *.

Point 3 should be a case executing a sql statement that either inserts new words with a count of 1 or updates the count of known words by 1.

**EDIT following comments**

Point 1 - build a list of words

```
var matches = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\\*[^ \t]+").Matches(textbox1);

foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Point 3 - store words for frequency list

```
//using statement to ensure connection is cleaned up correctly
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=StoreList;Integrated Security=sspi"))
{
    connection.Open();

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("UpdateWordFrequency", connection);

        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@word", match.Value));

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Where the procedure looks like this

```
create procedure UpdateWordFrequency
    @word varchar(50)
as
if not exists (select 1 from WordList where word = @word)
    insert into WordList (word, frequency) values (@word, 0)

update WordList set frequency = frequency + 1 where word = @word
```

And the WordList table has 2 fields **word** (varchar) and **frequency** (int)

Point 2 - output star'd words

Well this should now be a case of selecting from the WordList table

Comment: Yeah I understand how to do this without interaction with the database. But the whole point of the application is so that it uses the database so that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: You mean the whole point is the frequency list should be stored and retrievable from the database?

Comment: Yeah so if I enter "*brown" twice. It's stored in the database and counted 2 times. so it would print "*brown 2"

Comment: And what about existing entries made in the past e.g. Monday you enter *brown twice then Tuesday you enter *brown again - What you you expect to see on the Tuesday brown - 1 or brown - 3 (ie includes entries made Monday)?

Comment: It would show 3 *browns. So i'm permanently adding them to the database

Comment: A few errors, Regex brings the error: "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference" and I'm not too sure where to put that last part, the prodedure

Comment: Visual Studio should help you with this in that you can 'resolve' the using statement "using System.Text.RegularExpressions;"

Comment: I've updated the example to include the full namespace for Regex object.

Comment: The procedure needs to be run into your StoreList database

Comment: Everything is fine now apart from the line "(Match match in matches)" it gives the error: the namespace could not be found

Comment: Also, I presume changing the line "Console.WriteLine(match.Value);" to  "textbox2.Text = (match.Value);" will allow it to print the words in the second text box

Comment: Sorry, I've now managed to resolve it and it's showing no errors! But now when i run it, I get a login fail error. Any way to change the privileges?

Comment: You need to look at the connect string for the SqlConnnection class

Comment: If the SQL express instance is local to your machine the you really shouldn't be getting privilege issues.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to use a stored procedure for this.

By using a stored procedure you can do something like this:

```
create procedure Insert_StoreList
@Word nvarchar(50)
AS

insert StoreList (
item )
values (
@Word )

SELECT item FROM StoreList WHERE item LIKE '*%'
```

Then you can use the following in C#

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Insert_StoreList", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Word", Textbox1.Text));
SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
```

Edit - If you won't like to use stored procedures you can do this with 2 lines of SQL too, The first one would be an ExecuteNonQuery to get the value into the Table, and the second one would be to select all the words from the table.

The first sql would be:

```
String queryStr = "insert StoreList (item) values (" + Textbox1.Text + ")";
```

The second sql would be:

```
String queryStr = "SELECT item FROM StoreList WHERE item LIKE '*%'";
```

Comment: If I was to use a stored procedure, would I use the created database or is this creating one itself?

Comment: Hmm, I thought my code would be correct but I think it's just needing amended a little so it takes the word from textbox1

Comment: I disagree about Stored Procedures, they are very useful, and if set up correctly also a big help preventing SQL injections.

Comment: @Lex SQL injections can be prevented if you check the inputs correctly, there are always going to be problems with injection and other security issues but just using a stored procedure won't protect against it. Plus when editing your code, when you want to look at what a function does if it needs modification, you should be able to see it right there, rather than having to go into the SQL and change it.

Comment: @JakeJ using stored procedures or not is a personal preference. My work involves a lot of POS data needed to be stored and retrieved from many tables, having a stored procedure makes that a lot easier. And here we have several layers between the database and the actual data displayed, so editing the code you would still have to look at several layers of code.

Comment: @Lex We have multiple layers also but at the lowest level is all the SQL connectivity and queries to be run. I suppose it could be preference but as I said, all the developers that I have spoken to say otherwise

Comment: @JakeJ Not sure why Stored Procedures are a problem for you, considering any developer in the company I work for would always try to use stored procedures where possible, but that doesn't matter. All I did was giving a solution to a problem, it doesn't matter if one group of developers doesn't like stored procedures and another does, this site is to help each other, and I gave a solution on the way that I'm used to and I have been using for many years now.

Comment: @Lex Our company does not use stored procedures so that's a difference in company. If your answer works, it works so I have no problems with it, more of a do's and dont's than anything and it's a don't for me. I found another article to read through if you get the chance. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html

Comment: @JakeJ - care to elaborate, from your personal + professional perspective Stored Procedures are bad ? Rather than quoting other people ? Point me to your blog, please.

Comment: @YS I have no blog and have never used stored procedures in my past due to the reasons that I have read, Rather than trying to touch a wall that says 'Wet Paint' I'm reading the messages and reasons and not going to use them

Comment: Well I can probably find the same number (if not more) article in the internet that says ORM is bad, too. Would you then stop using SQL altogether and... perhaps starts using NoSQL :P

Comment: Is it possible for 2 flame wars to co-exist within one comments thread? orm vs sproc - sql vs nosql...